# Fabric.js and oCoords for canvas.loadFromJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have a Fabric.js application and I'm able to loadFromJson but when I call a mouse event I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oCoords' of undefined" error. This also happens while clicking on a blank canvas. 
Mouse events that call my functions:

canvas.on({
        'mouse:up': getLines,
        'object:moving': removeDim,
        'after:render': updateBnum
    });

I know that it's looking for the object, but I'm unsure how to get the object that's being clicked on.

Inside my getLines function I have this:

canvas.forEachObject(function(o) {...my code in here.})

I've tried o.setCoords() and canvas.renderAll() but it's not working.

For a new, blank canvas, I also get the same error but as soon as I draw some objects and click on the canvas all works well.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If the error occurs on a blank canvas, I'd assume there is something corrupt with the FabricJS library or other code on the page.

- What browser/version are you using?  Older browsers, in particular older IE, don't play nice with canvas elements.
- Have you tried updating the library to the latest version?
- Have you made any modifications to the FabricJS library?
- Is there other javascript code on the page that may be conflicting with FabricJS?

I'd start by stripping this down to as basic of a page and see if the problem persists - then try building up from there.